# Twisted. More than 1 ip address in dns reply

Tags: python, dns, twisted, reply

I use from twisted.names import dns for serving dns queries on my network.
And i want to reply with list of IP addresses for my domain ( example for  'mydomain22.com' query ) I use this sample for serving queries https://gist.github.com/johnboxall/1147973

```
    for answer in ans:
        if answer.type != dns.A:
            continue
        if domain['name'] not in answer.name.name:
            continue

        answer.payload.address = socket.inet_aton(list_of_ip) # here 
        answer.payload.ttl = TTL
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that `ans` is a list of `RRHeader` instances (but it's sad that I had to guess, try including this sort of information in your questions in the future :) which is used to populate the answers section of the DNS message your code sends as a response.

However, it's not obvious that my guess is correct because if it were correct then you'd already be able to send back multiple answers.  `ans` is a list of `RRHeader` instances and each of those instances will be included in the answer that is sent out.  So if you'd like more answers to be sent, just add more `RRHeader` instances to `ans`.

And of course, if the records are more suitable as *authority* or *additional* records, then put them into one of those lists instead of into the answers list.